# order of default parameter values important es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am hoping to clarify something.

ES6 brings us extended parameter handling and enables us to pass default parameter values.

```
function f (x, y = 7, z = 42) {
    return x + y + z
}

f(1) === 50
```

This works fine. However, if I swap the arguments so they look like this `(x = 7, y, z = 42)` it returns `NaN`.

```
function f (x = 7, y, z = 42) {
    return x + y + z
}

f(1) === 50
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: 1 will be the argument `x` which leaves `y` with no value.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks! so how do i ignore `x` so it takes the default. If that makes sense? Or does it just mean the first argument has to be the one that is undefined?

Comment: Use an object as the param instead? Give `y` a default value?

Comment: You can't ignore it. You'll have to pass in two parameters so `y` will have a value then you'll override the `x` vlaue.

Comment: Default parametters are usually on the **right** side in the argument list.

Comment: cool! thanks @ibrahimmahrir and do they only apply to `undefined`. if the argument passed is `null` it will overwrite, correct? i.e. in the first `example function f (x = 10, y = 7, z = 42) {
    return x + y + z
}` and then - 

`f(null)`

Comment: @peterflanagan `f(void 0 , 1, void 0)`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"If the call used `undefined` then `undefined` will be used as argument overriding the default parameter."_ The default parameter would be used when `undefined` is passed, yes? Using second `f` at Question `f(void 0, 1, void 0)//50`. At `foo(x = 10, y = 10, z = 10)` `f(null, undefined, null)` returns `10`

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah I think you're right. If `undefined` is passed then the default will be used!

Comment: ...that means you can ignore the first default using `foo(undefined, 1)` which will use the default value of the first argument and explicitly set the value of the second to `1`.

Comment: Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 5):

The order matters when you are passing the values into the function. In the first case, you are passing only one variable to the function. That value will be assigned to variable `x`. Since you are only passing one variable, the rest of the values for the other parameters are assumed to be null. However, since you have assigned default values for those parameters, the function would try to evaluate `1 + 7 + 52`, which resolves to 50.

In your second case, You are passing 1 as the value for variable `x`. Since parameter `y` is left unassigned, therefore the function will evaluate `1 + undefined + 42`, which is a `NaN` type.